# Codeigniter/PHP include re-useable functions in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, include

I have this function that is constantly being reused in my controllers. I have decided to move it into a file that can be referenced all the time. This is my file structure

```
controllers
|Generic
  |Users
    |get_all_languages.php
|Users
   |Lang
    |Lang.php
```

I want to reference get_all_languages which contains

```
<?php

function get_all_languages(){
   $this->curl->create(GetAllLanguages);
   $this->curl->http_login(REST_KEY_ID,REST_KEY_PASSWORD);
   return json_decode($this->curl->execute(),true);
}
```

So far, I have tried including it in the top of my file like:

```
<?php
include __DIR__.'/../../Generic/Users/get_all_languages.php';
class Lang extends CI_Controller{
```

However, when I try to use that function like $this->get_all_languages();, an error occurs saying Call to undefined method Lang::get_all_languages()

I have also tried to include it after the __contruct but it doesn't allow me to compile.

I hope someone can let me know how I can reference that function.

Thank you.

Comment: My constant is global so it should be fine. How do I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `library` or `helper` of codeigniter.

And you can load them automatically in `application/config/autoload.php`.([Reference it](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html))

If you want the specific controller, you can use it in construct of controller using `$this->load->library()` or `$this->load->helper()`.

For example:

```
class A extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->library('libraryname');
       $this->load->helper('helpername');
    }

    public function index() {...}
    ...
}
```

...

**Updated**

```
application/helpers/global_lang_helper.php

<?php
function get_all_languages(){
   $CI = &get_instance();
   $CI->load->library('curl');
   $CI->curl->create(GetAllLanguages);
   $CI->curl->http_login(REST_KEY_ID,REST_KEY_PASSWORD);
   return json_decode($CI->curl->execute(),true);
}
```

At your controller...

```
public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->helper('global_lang');
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but I just want to load them in specific controllers. If I autoload it, won't it be available to the entire application? Could you give an example?

Comment: I have moved the files into the helper directory under applications. Currently its applications/helpers/Users/get_all_languages_helper.php. I have referenced it in my constructor as $this->load->helper('Users/get_all_languages'); However the same error happens.

Comment: @JianYA, please wait a moment, I will update my answer following your specific question.